# La aplicación angular en go dady no carga ninguna página

Tags: angular, deployment, godaddy

Tengo un problema, había implementado mi aplicación angular y alojado en go dady, todo estaba bien, se mostraban todas las páginas, pero decidí actualizar la versión php de mi alojamiento, así que ahora no me llevan a ningún otro lado, solo una pantalla en blanco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Posiblemente sea problema de configuración de `.htaccess`. Lo tienes agregado?.

Comment: Es raro porque si agrego un archivo html cualquier, este si se renderiza. Cuando subo el compilado de angular el <app-root> </app-root>  está en blanco, cuando debería verse el componente princiapal.

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta, pon la en español para que la abran de nuevo. Estas usando en `index.html` la etiqueta ` <base href="/" />`?

Comment: Si. Cuando abro la consola no me muestra ningún error relacionado a algun problema ocasionado por no encontrar los recurso, causado por el tag <base>

Comment: Agregué imagen de la consola

Comment: No creo que sea problema de php puesto que en angular todo es javascript. Si te fijas, la consola si te esta marcando un error de sintaxis. `Unexpected end of input` Intenta compilar de nuevo tu aplicacion con `ng build --prod ` y si te da error, actualiza la pregunta con la traza.